# Give angular router parameters without being in url

Tags: angular, router

I just want to navigate into my app with Angular Router and get the following result :

Url: '/transmission?kid_id=6'

I have this code :`this.router.navigate(['/transmissions'], {queryParams : {kid_id: kid.id}});`

But I want to add parameters without them being in url. I knwo How to send and receive them in another component.

Comment: Why don't you want them in the URL? That will cause problems if e.g. the client refreshes the page.

Comment: I don't think about the refresh, I'll make another method. Thanks !!

Comment: if you don't want to show those params in url. I will suggest you to store that in service and retrieve from service.